# Destroying sessions on different servers

Tags: php, session

I have made a basic login system that works as it should.

I use `session_start()` on all pages. I set my session variable with `$_SESSION = 'user';`

And I destroy it with `session_start(); session_destroy();`

**My problem is:**

If I write this code on my schools servers it works. But if I try it on my own server, I can login, but I cant destroy the session properly. When I click 'logout' and get sent to another page, I can just click back to the login-required-page as if I did not log in. That does not happen when I do it on my schools server.

Is there any way different versions of PHP can interfere with a basic session_destroy code?

Comment: If you go back to that page do you refresh it too? Maybe the browser keeps it in it's cache untill you reload the page.

Comment: its called browser cache.

Comment: session_destroy does not delete the cookie. How do you test if the user is logged in?

Comment: `session_destroy();` doesn't always do what I'd expect, this is cargo culting I'm sure but I usually `unset($_SESSION)` too

Comment: But the wierd thing is, that I try both pages (one from school, and one from home) on the same computer, and delete all cookies + cache when I do it

Answer (score 0):

First off `session_start();` starts the session, and `session_destroy();` destroys it.
You don't need to start sessions on all pages. You would do that after/or in login loop. As for destroying session, you should use it when you logout. Ofcourse, after you do that you should redirect user to home page or somewhere else (up to you).

I'd recomend you to read [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922187/needing-guidance-on-how-to-redirect-a-user-if-not-logged-in-on-admin-panel/14922416#14922416) about sessions and user restrictions/access on specific pages.
Hope this helps you.
P.S. After logging out try to refresh your page with `Ctrl + F5` (you probably have cached copy in your browser)

Answer (score -1):

you can't, as session is stored on your file system, so you have two instances of same session over servers.

A decent option for this case would be storing sessions in database, so your session management would be centralised.